# Passing Timestamp in the SQL Query to filter results

Tags: datetime, database

I've a query where I want to filter query results based on today, yesterday and week. I've written queries within Drupal 7 and it is as follows:-

```
$result = db_query("
    SELECT
  n.title, n.nid,
  COUNT(*) AS times
FROM
  {node_view_count} a, {node} n where a.nid = n.nid AND a.uid = :uid AND n.nid <> 2120 AND DATE(from_unixtime(:mydate)) = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY
  n.title
ORDER BY
  times desc",
array(':uid'=>$_GET['uid'], ':mydate'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s', "a.timestamp") )) -> fetchAll();
```

My question is, that could I pass two variables in the array as a parameter? Also if I could why is this query not working when I pass two parameters in it. The problem is that I need to convert the timestamp to date before using it and I am using a query Variable in the parameters.

Do you think you could assist in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably because you're using `FROM_UNIXTIME` on a parameter that you've converted into a formatted date string. Just pass the timestamp integer for `:mydate` and test again

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of D7 handy, but this seems to work on D6 for me. There's at least two problems with your code. I'm going to pare your query into a short bit of SQL, then transform it into drupal code.

### Use `JOIN`s

Whenever you're using multiple tables in SQL, you'll almost always have to use the `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax. Using `JOIN` tells MySQL that you want to connect certain rows on the two tables if a given field from those tables matches. This is a very basic SQL concept, so you'll need to master this if you want to write your own SQL or troubleshoot it. [Try W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for a better explanation.

Here's a simplified, pure SQL query that works for me using a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  n.title, n.nid, COUNT(*) as times
FROM
  node n 
JOIN
  node_view_count a
ON
    a.nid = n.nid
GROUP BY
    n.title
ORDER BY times DESC;
```

In my D6 installation, I have a table called `node_counter`, but you probably have `node_view_count` instead on D7. `JOIN node_view_count` tells MySQl that we're connecting the `node` table to the `node_view_count` table. The `ON a.nid = n.nid` tells MySQL to only connect rows from these two tables when the `nid` field matches.

### `WHERE` Clause

Next, let's add in a simplified `WHERE` clause. On my D6 database, the `node_counter` table's `timestamp` field is an unix timestamp (an integer). We can do the conversion from unix timestamp to datetime using pure SQL as well (no need to use a parameter to `db_query()`):

```
...
ON
    a.nid = n.nid
WHERE
    DATE(from_unixtime(a.timestamp)) = "2012-12-21"
GROUP BY
...
```

### Add a Paramater to `db_query()`

We can change "2012-12-21" to whatever date we want to search on. So, next let's make this changeable part of our query into a parameter that gets passed to `db_query()`:

```
<?php
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT
  n.title, n.nid, COUNT(*) as times
FROM
  {node} n 
JOIN
  {node_view_count} a
ON
    a.nid = n.nid
WHERE
    DATE(from_unixtime(a.timestamp)) = :mydate
GROUP BY
    n.title
ORDER BY times DESC
SQL;
```

I've put `{` and `}` around the table names so that you use this query inside `db_query()`. By adding `:mydate`, you can now add in parameter called ':mydate' with a date string to your `db_query()` call:

```
$result = db_query($query, array(':mydate' => '2012-12-21'));
```

Hopefully, this gets you 90% of the way there.